# How to set values based on a date range in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to set values based on a arrival and departure date:

```
Idx    Arrive    Depart    01. Jan    02. Jan    03. Jan    04. Jan    05. Jan    ...
 1     01. Jan   04. Jan      1          1          1
 2     02. Jan   04. Jan                 1          1
 3     02. Jan   05. Jan                 1          1          1          
 4     01. Jan   05. Jan      1          1          1          1          
 5     03. Jan   05. Jan                            1          1
...    ...       ...         ...        ...        ...        ...        ...      ...

                 Total        2          4          5          3
```

For example, Idx 1:

Arrives on 01 January
Departs on 04 January
A total of 3 nights accommodation needed (value of '1' in the columns 01, 02 and 03 January) You'll note that a '1' isn't entered in the 04 January column, as this is the date of departure and no accommodation isn't required that night.

How to archieve this in Excel?

Comment: could you please start approving answers to all your still open questions? If the right answer isnt there please explain better what the problem is. Also read the FAQ please for how to best formulate your questions (include code, explain clearly and in some detail what you tried and how that failed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that *Arrive* is in column A and the column headers (*Arrive*, *Depart*, *01. Jan*) are on row 1, you want to put the following formula into cell C2:

```
=IF(AND(C$1>=$A2,C$1<$B2),1,"")
```

From there, you can copy the formula into the other cells. The formula assumes that the dates on the left and at the top are proper data values, i.e. Excel treats them as dates.

Comment: Excel says the formula contains errors. Arrive is in column B and the column headers are on row 1. I tried to change the formula to =IF(AND(C$1>=$B2,C$1<$B2),1,"") with no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Found it! This worked for me. =IF(AND(D$1>=$A2;D$1<$B2);1;"")

Comment: Whether a comma or a semicolon is required depends on your Excel's language settings.